# Let $f,g \in L^2$, find the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\|f+tg\|_2-\|f\|_2}{t}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image]

Let $f,g \in L^2$, find the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\|f+tg\|_2-\|f\|_2}{t}$. My guess is that the limit is $\|g\|_2$ as applying Minkowski gives us this as an upper bound for the limit. I was not successful however, in showing that this is in fact the limit.

Comment: There seems to be something off here. The limit is the same as $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\|f+tg\|_2}{t}$. Are you sure $t\to\infty$ and not $t\to 0$ (ie. trying to compute a sort of derivative)?

Comment: @volJunkie Yes I am sure. Does the limit exist if $t \to 0$?

Comment: Yes, you can do $$\frac{\|f+tg\| - \|f\|}{t} = \frac{\|f+tg\|^2 - \|f\|^2}{t}\frac{1}{\|f+tg\| + \|f\|} = \frac{2\langle f, g\rangle + t\|g\|^2}{\|f+tg\| + \|f\|}\to \frac{\langle f, g\rangle}{\|f\|}.$$

Comment: @volJunkie Ah I see, That would explain the extra assumption $||f||>0$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. I'm going to do a little trick here to make this more manageable. Let's assume $t>0$ since it's trending to $+\infty$ anyway, so

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\|f+tg\|-\|f\|}{t} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t\|t^{-1}f+g\|-t\|t^{-1}f\|}{t} = \lim_{t\to\infty} (\|t^{-1}f+g\|-\|t^{-1}f\|).$$

A simple rewrite of $r = t^{-1}$ will make this limit clearer. Can you take it from here? Inherent in the final step is that norms are continuous functions.

Comment: Ah! The mention of continuity did it for me! I was actually considering this line but could not justify moving the limit inside. The reason we can do this is because $f_n=\frac{f}{n}$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$, correct?

Comment: Yeah that'll suffice for rough reasoning. Really, $t_n$ should be any sequence converging to $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't the last $+$ be a $-$?

Comment: Oh geez. Yep good catch @ClementC. I was thinking about another approach to this problem that involved "rationallizing" the numerator and it snuck through at the last second.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{||f+tg||-||f||}{t} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\left|\left|\frac{f}{t}+g\right|\right|-\frac{||f||}{t}\right)=||g||$$